# Android application not responds after secondary ACTION_PICK intent

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-camera

I have created fragment with multiple image addition dialog. Each image can be added via camera or gallery. In both situations I can add only one image - after dismissing gallery/camera view application stops responding.
That's how I create camera and gallery pick intent:

```
//permissions request in other methods
private void pickImage() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_GALLERY);
}

private void openCamera() {
    if (PermissionsHelper.checkStoragePermissions(ReportFragment.this)) {
        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        fileFromCamera = fileUri.getPath();
        takePicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        startActivityForResult(takePicture, SELECT_PHOTO);
    } else {
        PermissionsHelper.requestStoragePermissions(this, CAMERA_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Here is how result handled:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }
    if (requestCode == SELECT_GALLERY) {
        Uri selectedImageAddress = data.getData();
        addPathsIfUnique(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageAddress));
    }
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO) {
        if (PermissionsHelper.checkStoragePermissions(this)) {
            if(fileFromCamera != null) {
                addPathsIfUnique(fileFromCamera);
            }
        } else {
            PermissionsHelper.requestStoragePermissions(this, CAMERA_STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}

private void addPathsIfUnique(String path) {
    if(path == null)
        return;
    for(String currentPath : photoPaths) {
        if(currentPath.equals(path)) {
            return;
        }
    }
    photoPaths.add(path);
    shopChanged(point);
}
```

In the shopChanged function I'm recreating ListView cells. I was also trying to completely remove ListView, replace it with single button in fragment, but result was same: after second time opened gallery or camera closed, application becomes  not responding. Even OnResume breakpoint not fired. But after first opening all works good.
What can be reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What does your `onRequestPermissionsResult` look like?  I'm guessing you  have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: Looks like this: http://pastebin.com/eY9QjBM5 But after all permissions granted, error still exists. Now I commented out this method, and application become not responsible even after first gallery opening:) Now I have to create new empty project and step by step copy existing code to find the reason

Comment: Do you solve this problem if yes give me solution I am also facing this problem

Comment: see comment below - downgrade to google play services 8.4.0 solved issue

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: this is new Google Play Services bug - issue fixed after downgrade to 8.4.0. Will search they bugtracker and submit bug, if it isn't submitted already